# How to use OpenCV in a C++ file on the Google Colab?

Tags: opencv, jupyter, google-colaboratory

I can successfully use OpenCV on my laptop for reading/processing images in C++ using VisualStudio.

On the Google Colab however, I get into problem.

The OpenCV is pre-installed on Colab, so we should be able to use it simply, but I fail to do it!

Can anyone post me a simple imread/imshow in C++ on the Google Colab from scratch?

P.S.: I assume there is no need to install anything on Jupyter, since OpenCV 4.7.0 is already installed on the jupyter.
After typing the program in the Colab Jupyter Command Line, I simply Ctrl+Enter to run it.

Here is a snapshot of my code, assuming we are in the content folder (default) which fails to run, because of this error:

fatal error: …/usr/include/opencv4/opencv2/opencv_modules.hpp: No such file or directory
6 | #include "…/usr/include/opencv4/opencv2/opencv_modules.hpp"

undefined reference to `cv::imread

```
%%cu
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include "…/usr/include/opencv4/opencv2/opencv_modules.hpp"
#include "…/usr/include/opencv4/opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include "…/usr/include/opencv4/opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "…/usr/include/opencv4/opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "…/usr/include/opencv4/opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "iostream"

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

#ifdef _DEBUG
#pragma comment (lib, "opencv_world412d.lib")
#else
#pragma comment (lib, "opencv_world412.lib")
#endif

int main()
{
//I have already uploaded this image into Colab folder: remastered-lena-512x512.tiff
const char* img_color_name = "remastered-lena-512x512.tiff";
cv::Mat img;
img = cv::imread(img_color_name);
// wait for a key
cv::waitKey(0);
}
```

Comment: Please check your code above and correct auto-formatted characters like quotes. Please add the command that you use to compile and link the code. This way it easier for others to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Don’t confuse having runtime libraries installed with having development headers installed. It is the latter which isn’t being found